# converting datetime format with multiple datatypes into date format in excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, vba

i have a datetime in the format : 26FEB2016:00:00:00.000000 in my excel sheet
i want it to be in 02/26/2016 format.
I tried using the format tool but it dint work. 
How can i do this conversion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `:` between the date and the time.

You can do this with a formula:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":"," ",1)
```

Then format the cell in manner of your choosing.

[image]

Comment: @DPatel In a few minutes a check mark by the answer will be available.  Please click on it to mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.